# How can i loop through each line in a file and assign variables to the lines

Tags: python

I am trying to read each line of a file and then assign every 3 line into the same variables. So for example I have a file that is as follows:

```
james
male
32
julie
female
29
mark
male
35
```

I want to iterate through the list and print every record out with name, gender and age beside the relevant lines or  when i search by name i.e 'James', i want the output to say:

```
name: james
gender:male
age: 32
```

so far I am able to place all the lines in the text file into a list but I cant figure out how iterate through the list to assign each line to the variables name, gender, age

```
fileList = []
print("This function prints the records out one by one")
file2 = open(fileName, "r")
file_line = file2.readlines()
file_line = [x.strip() for x in file_line]
for line in file_line:
    fileList.append(line)
print(fileList)
print("Name: {}\nGender:: {}\nAge: {}\n".format(fileList[0], fileList[1], fileList[2]))
```

This allows me to access the lines when i specifically select their position in the list but i want it to iterate through the entire list and print every thing in the list or print a particular persons record when i search by name

Comment: what if the order changes somewhere, e.g. "mark, 36, male"? Trusting in such 'structures' can be dangerous; if your 'database' gets bigger, there are more useful formats like csv, json, ...

Answer (score 2):

The crux of the solution is that you need to read three lines at a time. Luckily, since file objects behave like iterators, you can just use the open file object three times, in a zip

```
with open(fileName) as infile:
    for name, gender, age in zip(infile, infile, infile):
        print("name:", name)
        print("gender:", gender)
        print("age:", age)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here in principal is read the file in chunks of a certain size (3 lines per chunk in this case). inspectorG4dget's nice answer gave me the idea to the following, more versatile but admittedly also more complicated option. borrowing from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#recipes), one can use the function `grouper()` to get chunks of a defined size from the file (3 in this case):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    chunks_gen = grouper(infile, 3, fillvalue='')
    for chunk in chunks_gen:
        print("Name: {}Gender: {}Age: {}".format(*chunk))
```

also prints

```
Name: james
Gender: male
Age: 32

Name: julie
Gender: female
Age: 29

Name: mark
Gender: male
Age: 35
```

Comment: This is quite helpful, thank you. ill try this option, inspectorG4dget solution works for what i need, but this definitely gave me something new to work with.